# Selecting and filtering the list of Excel sheets with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

For every Excel sheet there exist a variable *var1*.

I want to write a VBA expression, that would select Excel sheets, on which the value of variable *var1* is the same.

How can I get the list of all sheets? And then filter it denepnding on *var1* values?

Comment: The value of the variable `var1` is the same as what?

Comment: You might want to provide some sort of example... sample data or a screen shot or something.  It is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go through the sheets, you can use a FOR EACH loop.  Replace ActiveWorkbook with your workbook, if possible.

```
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        <do things; 'Sheet' is an object now that takes on the properties 
          of each sheet in the workbook one at a time.>
Next Sheet
```

Once you're in that loop you can check for var1 and do whatever you like.  I'm not entirely sure what you mean by variable var1 on each sheet, you may want to clarify that some as the comments note.

Comment: This doesn't appear to meant the intent of a vaguely worded question.